# Binary-searching XML from disk in a SAX-like way - wise? Possible?

Tags: xml, ios, xml-parsing, sax, binary-search

I find myself needing to search through a (potentially) large XML file for items with a specific timestamp at within-an-animation-frame type speeds.

I've been doing something similar in a recent project, but there the XML was small enough to fit in memory, so I parsed it out into an array of simple objects and binary-searched it. BOOM! super-quick search through 800-odd timestamped items per-frame.

This time around, the XML files might well be large enough to make parsing them out into memory a stupid idea (this is iOS stuff, so RAM is limited).  The solution in my head is to do SAX-like stream parsing from a file, but with a settable pointer. So I could jump that pointer around the file in another binary search, parse the next complete node in the file, and use that to inform where the search pointer jumps next.

A good theory, I think. However, looking around the internets, I haven't been able to find a SAX parser that allows setting of its current line number in the file. Many give you read-only access as a status, but none allow that oh-so-crucial position setting.

SO. Does anyone know of an XML parsing lib that has such an ability? Again, this is iOS world, so anything C/C++ based would do, but bonus points if it has an Obj-C wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that safely in XML, at least not directly. You said you want to jump to a certain line number, but that might not help you, because XML is not line based. And you can't easily jump to *n*-th child of some node, because that requires fully parsing the XML.

What you can do is to first parse the whole file and create an index: for each node (of those you need to jump to) you remember its start position in the file (probably in as a byte offset). And you can do this using SAX (or SAX-like) parser, you don't need to have the whole document in memory.

If you do it this way, you have to parse the whole file once (O(n) operation), but you can then jump any node and parse quickly (in O(1)), which should make the binary search performant.

Or you could create the index based on the property you want to search. If you do this, the whole binary search will be in-memory and you can parse just the one (or few) node you need, which should be even faster.